# How can I prevent Photos.app from being launched on OS X?

Tags: macos, photos.app

I am trying to find a way to either delete Photos.app (or any other built-in for that matter) or stop it from ever launching (until I decide otherwise).

By the way, I have disabled the auto-launch when I connect a device. But I don't want Photos.app to suggest that I should convert my Aperture library by just clicking on one button. If other people are using my Mac this could happen and did before. Then I have to go in and manually edit my precious library again and I am afraid of destroying the hundreds of hours of work that I already put into it.

Comment: Sounds like it would be a lot simpler to not let others use your main login. Set them up with their own.

Comment: I also don't want OSX to be able to launch the app

Answer (score 2):

Maybe creating a separate user account for `Others` and move `/Applications/Photos.app/` to `/Users/Others/Applications/Photos.app` and change the ownership of that helps you.

Comment: You could leave the app where it is. Other users would not be able to access the first user's library structure anyway, so the problem would simply not arise, even if they did launch Photos.